# List of objects not displayed because undefined in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, typescript, spring-boot, angular-material

I have a list of `Question` , every object of type `Question` has a 1:n relationship with objects of type `Answer` (so every `Question` object has a list of `Answer` objects). I'm trying to display on the browser, using Angular material, all the `Question` objects with their answers after a click event, but when I try to do so, the `Question` objects are displayed without their answers. After some researches I found out that even if the `Answer` and `Question` objects are correcty "connected" and stored in the database, the list of answers results to be undefined as shown in the following console:

> {id: 10, question: 'Question1', questionsForUser: Array(0), answers:
> undefined}
> Answers: homepage.component.ts:32
> undefined
> homepage.component.ts:33

How can I deal with this problem?

Here is the relationship between `Question` and `Answer`:

[image]

homepage.component is the component in which the following click event occurs:

```
<div class="button">
          <button mat-button (click)="getQuestions()" routerLink="questions/getAllQuestions" routerLinkActive="active">Show</button>
</div>
```

homepage.component.ts:

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  longText = `...`;
  public questions: Question[] = [];

  constructor(private questionService: QuestionService, private  shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.castQuestions.subscribe(questions=>this.questions=questions);
  }

  public getQuestions():void{
    this.questionService.getQuestions().subscribe(
      (response: Question[]) => {
        this.questions =response;

        this.shared.showQuestions(this.questions);
        console.log(response);
        for(let i=0; i<response.length; i++){
          this.questions[i].answers=response[i].answers;
          console.log(response[i]);
          console.log("Answers:");
          console.log(response[i].answers);
        }

      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

After the click event, thanks to Angular routing, the tool.component code should be executed.

tool.component.html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="questions" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 
  <!-- Question Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="question">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Question </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let question"> {{question.question}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Answers Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="answers">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Answers </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let question"> {{question.answers}} </td>
  </ng-container>



  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

tool.component.ts:

```
export class ToolComponent implements OnInit {
  public questions: Question[] = [];
  displayedColumns = ['question', 'answers'];
  constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.castQuestions.subscribe(questions=>this.questions=questions);
  }

}
```

shared.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
    private questions= new BehaviorSubject<Array<Question>>([]);
      castQuestions = this.questions.asObservable();

    showQuestions(data: Question[]){
      this.questions.next(data);

  }
}
```

console.log(response):

[image]

question.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
public getQuestions(): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.http.get<Question[]>('http://localhost:8080/questions/getAllQuestions');
  }
}
```

Back/api with which I create the response:

Question entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "question", schema = "purchase")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "question", nullable = true, length = 1000)
    private String question;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<QuestionForUser> questionsForUser;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

Answer entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer", schema = "purchase")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "answer", nullable = true, length = 1000)
    private String answer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question")

    private Question question;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

QuestionRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer> {

    List<Question> findByQuestionContaining(String question);

    boolean existsByQuestion(String question);

}
```

QuestionService:

```
@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions(){
        return questionRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

QuestionController:

```
@GetMapping("/getAllQuestions")
    public List<Question> getAll(){
        List<Question> ques = questionService.getAllQuestions();
        for(Question q:ques){
            System.out.println(q.getQuestion());
            if(q.getAnswers()!=null){
                System.out.println("The answers are: "+q.getAnswers().size());
            }
        }

        return questionService.getAllQuestions();
    }
```

As suggested, I tried to add a test to `getAll()` in `QuestionController`. To make the test return a string, I temporarily changed the method `getAll()` in this way:

```
@GetMapping("/getAllQuestions")//funziona
    public String getAll(){
        List<Question> result = questionService.getAllQuestions();
        String answer = result.get(0).getAnswers().get(0).getAnswer();
        return answer;
    }
```

Then, I wrote the following test:

```
class QuestionControllerTest {

    @Test
    void getAll() {
        QuestionController controller = new QuestionController(); //Arrange
        String response = controller.getAll(); //Act
        assertEquals("a1", response); //Assert
    }
}
```

The first answer of the first question should be `a1`, but when I execute the test on IntelliJ I have the following result:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "com.ptoject.demo.services.QuestionService.getAllQuestions()" because
> "this.questionService" is null
>
> at
> com.ptoject.demo.controller.QuestionController.getAll(QuestionController.java:64)
> at
> com.ptoject.demo.controller.QuestionControllerTest.getAll(QuestionControllerTest.java:12)
> <31 internal calls> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)<9 internal
> calls> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)<25 internal
> calls>

Comment: Please, add to your question a snapshot/capture of your console for this instruction: **console.log(response);**

Comment: Sure, I just added the snapshot. @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero

Comment: As I was afraid, you are getting the undefined from your back/API. Its nothing that you can do in the Angular front to solve it. You should have the problem in your "back" side (*unless you have a problem  in your "questionService" service, in the ""getQuestions" method*).I recommend you to **add to your question the code of that method "getQuestions()**, and the code of the back/API with which you create that 'response' object.

Comment: I'll add the questionService service  and the code of the back/API too. Thanks @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero

Comment: Definitely, the problem does not seem to be in 'getQuestions' method, but in your back-end.  **Add the tag of the language you are using in back to your original question**.

Comment: Can you add a test mapping to your controller? If so, please make it return a single String and test it with Postman or curl. I'm not really experienced with this, but I suspect you might need to serialize your data (`Question`) before responding it.

Comment: I'm new to the topic and, unfortunately, I don't know how to add a test mapping... @JettoMartínez

Comment: @JettoMartínez I edited my question trying to add the test that you suggested (even if I don't know how to test it with Postman), but an error occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on `List<Answer> answers` field in your `Question` entity class. This is telling Jackson to ignore (i.e. don't include) this field when serializing the object into JSON.

To fix this:

1. In your **`Question`** entity class, remove the `@JsonIgnore` annotation from the `List<Answer> answers` field
2. On the other hand, in your **`Answer`** entity class you should add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the `Question question` field -- this is to avoid potential [Jackson infinite recursion issue](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) caused by the bidrection relationship.

Question entity:

```
...
public class Question {
    ...

    // remove @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Answer> answers;
    ...
}
```

Answer entity:

```
...
public class Answer {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question")
    @JsonIgnore // add this here
    private Question question;
    ...
}
```